# tcl's subst seems slower than set, when getting a variable value from a variable with a variable's name

Tags: performance, variables, runtime, tcl

See Tcl 8.4 code below and shell output below: (I need meta- coding):

```
% set k a
% set m k
% puts [set $m ]
a
% puts [subst $$m]
a
```

So, it appear that `set $m` and `subst $$m` have the same functionality. However, the runtime (in the simple testcase) is rather different (see continuation of shell results below:

```
% time { set $m } 1000000
0.256435 microseconds per iteration
% time { subst $$m } 1000000
0.627714 microseconds per iteration
```

As can be seen, set is ~2.5 faster than subst. 2 questions are: to be asked:
1. Why?
2. I have seen that it is ~3.6  faster in Tcl 8.5. Can we expect that this will remain the case, in future releases?
Thanks

Comment: and let's keep this in perspective: we're talking less than one microsecond.

Comment: True. But what happens if you have to do that hundreds of millions of times?

Comment: Well, half a microsecond per iteration times 500 million iterations is about 4 minutes. Certainly worth looking at but probably not your biggest bottleneck.

Comment: Nope. But this code may be used later, in something that is accessed billions of times ( VLSI chip transistors ), and ran many times, on an expensive license EDA SW, it is beginning to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expect things to remain exactly the same. When you use:

```
puts [set $m]
```

Tcl will compile that once to a read of the `m` variable (storing the result on the internal operation stack) a read of the variable whose name is on the operation stack, and then a call of `puts` with the result.

When you do:

```
puts [subst $$m]
```

Tcl compiles that to a concatenation of `$` and the results of reading `m`, a call to the substitution engine (which in turn will parse and bytecode compile that fragment) and only then a `puts` of the result. Which is entirely more complicated.

You'd see the difference if you did:

```
set m {k[exit]}
```

The first would just tell you that you were trying to read from a (strangely-named) variable that didn't exist. The second would quit the process.

Comment: Actually, the speed difference will be larger in Tcl 8.6 than in 8.5, as `subst` of non-constant strings got a performance hit there. On the other hand, `subst` of _constant_ strings got a performance boost. (It stems from how things were enabled for the non-recursive evaluation engine.)

Comment: Would specifying -nocommands and -nobackslashes aid performance at all?

Comment: @glennjackman Probably not very much; that just changes exactly what happens in response to `[` and `\ `, but they still have to be parsed (since we don't swap parsers right now). You're still having an extra parse with `subst` (with bytecode generation in 8.6) in addition to the variable lookup(s) required in both cases. If dynamic variable names are being used, it's usually best to `upvar 0` them to a fixed local alias…